# Pandas Series boolean maps and plotting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean, plotly, series

I am just trying to up my understanding of plotting Pandas Series data using Booleans to mask out values I don't want. I am not sure that what I have is the correct or efficient way to do it.

Don't get me wrong, I do get the chart I am after but are my assumptions on the syntax correct?

All I want to do is plot the non zero values on my chart. I have not formatted the charts as I would normally as this was just a test of Booleans and masking data and not for creating report grade charts.

If I masked this as a Pandas DataFrame I would do the following if df1 were my DataFrame.
I understand this and it makes sense that the df1[mask] returns my values as required

```
# Plot our graph with only items that are non-zero
fig = px.bar(df1[mask], x = 'Animals', y = 'Count')
fig.show()
```

Doing it as a Pandas Series
This is the snippet that creates the graph I require

```
# Plot our graph with only items that are non-zero
fig = px.bar(sf, x = sf.index[sf_mask], y = sf[sf_mask])
fig.show()
```

After my initial test with adding my mask to sf and getting an error. I deduced that I needed to add the mask against the x and y parameters. I take it this is because a Series is just a single column and the index is set as my "animals". Therefore by mapping the sf.index[sf_mask] I get the returned animals in the index and sf[sf_mask] returns me the values. failure to add either one would give a "ValueError" stating that the arguments should have the same length.

Here is what I did to test my workings

My initial imports and setting up Plotly as my plotting backend

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Set our plotting backend to Plotly
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
```

I just created a test dataset from a dictionary

```
animals = {'rabbits' : 1,
       'dogs' : 3,
       'cats' : 0,
       'ferrets' : 3,
       'horses' : 8,
       'goldfish' : 0,
       'guinea_pigs' : 2,
       'hamsters' : 6,
       'mice' : 3,
       'rats' : 0
      }
```

Then converted it to a pandas Series

```
sf = pd.Series(animals)
```

I then create my boolean mask to mask out all our non-Zero entries on our Pandas Series

```
sf_mask = sf != 0
```

And if I then view the mask I can see I only get non zero values which is exactly what I am looking for.

```
sf[sf_mask]
```

Which outputs my non-zero items in my series.

```
rabbits        1
dogs           3
ferrets        3
horses         8
guinea_pigs    2
hamsters       6
mice           3
dtype: int64
```

If I plot without my Boolean mask 'sf_mask' using the following syntax I get my complete Pandas Series charted

```
# Plot our Series showing all items
fig = px.bar(sf, x = sf.index, y = sf)
fig.show()
```

Which outputs the following chart
[image: Pandas Series Charting all items]

If I plot with my Boolean mask 'sf_mask' using the following syntax I get the chart I want which excludes the gaps with zero value items.

```
# Plot our graph with only items that are non-zero
fig = px.bar(sf, x = sf.index[sf_mask], y = sf[sf_mask])
fig.show()
```

Which outputs the correct chart.
[image: Pandas Series Charting Non-Zero items]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of booleans and masking is correct.

You can simplify your syntax a little though: if you take a look at the plotly.express.bar [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar), you'll see that the arguments `'x'` and `'y'` are optional. You don't need to pass `'x'` or `'y'` because by default plotly.express will create the bars using the index of the Series as x and the values of the Series as y. You can also pass the masked series in place of the entire series.

For example, this will produce the same bar chart:

```
fig = px.bar(sf[sf>0])
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Derek That tip at the end was really helpful

Comment: @twelsh37 you're welcome – happy to have helped!